# Capture Helm Package name once it is formed

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to do a helm package deployment using Jenkins pipeline.
I am able to package the charts and deploy it. But in order to make it a dynamic deployment, I want to get the package name once formed & pass it down for further processing.

I have tried below options for groovy, but the variable "packageNm" is not getting any value.

```
def packageNm = sh(script: "cd ${appName}; printf '%s\n' ${appName}*.tgz", returnStatus: true)
def packageNm = sh(script: "helm package hello-helm -d hello-helm", returnStatus: true)
```

Any way to get this file name?
I even tried to search the file in workspace but the variable name is still empty

Comment: You need `returnStdout: true` also.

Comment: yes, that solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `returnStdout` instead of `returnStatus` for getting the standard output into the variable.